# Recursive clustering algorithm using WITH RECURSIVE

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to implement a recursive clustering algorithm. Here is my code:

```
with data as(
select at2."name" as area_type, a.name,bf.* from building_footprints bf
left join area a on bf."areaID" = a."ID"
left join area_type at2 on at2."ID" = a."areaTypeID"
where a."ID" in (select "areaID" from campaign_scope)
and at2."name"='Uc'
)
,
dbscan as(
select data.*,ST_ClusterDBSCAN(st_transform(data."geoJson",24313),eps := 50, minPoints := 1) 
  OVER(ORDER BY data."ID") AS cluster_id from data)
,

filter as(
select cluster_id,count("ID") from dbscan
group by cluster_id
having count("ID") < 10
) 

,

accepted_dbscan as
(
select area_type, name,"ID","geoJson", "cluster_id",1 AS iteration from dbscan 
where cluster_id in (select cluster_id from filter)

)
,

rejected_dbscan as 
(
select * from dbscan 
where cluster_id not in (select cluster_id from filter)
)


,
kmeans AS (
    SELECT
        "area_type",
        "name",
        "ID",
        "geoJson",
        ST_ClusterKMeans(rejected_dbscan."geoJson", (SELECT (count(*) / 10)::integer FROM rejected_dbscan)) OVER (ORDER BY rejected_dbscan."ID") AS cluster_id,
        1 AS iteration
    FROM rejected_dbscan
),
finalset AS (
    SELECT * FROM kmeans
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM accepted_dbscan
),
recursive_cluster AS (
    SELECT
        "area_type",
        "name",
        "ID",
        "geoJson",
        cluster_id,
        iteration
    FROM finalset
    WHERE cluster_id IN (SELECT cluster_id FROM filter)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        "area_type",
        "name",
        "ID",
        "geoJson",
        ST_ClusterKMeans(fc.geoJson, (SELECT (count(*) / 10)::integer FROM fc)) OVER (ORDER BY fc."ID") AS cluster_id,
        rc.iteration + 1

    FROM recursive_cluster rc -- error here

    INNER JOIN finalset fc ON rc.cluster_id = fc.cluster_id
    WHERE rc.iteration < 2 
)
SELECT cluster_id, count(*) AS bfp_count
FROM recursive_cluster
GROUP BY cluster_id
ORDER BY bfp_count DESC;
```

This gives the following error:

```
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "recursive_cluster" does not exist
  Detail: There is a WITH item named "recursive_cluster", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
  Hint: Use WITH RECURSIVE, or re-order the WITH items to remove forward references.
  Position: 1716
```

The error occurs in the recursive_cluster CTE, with the exact line commented above. I do not understand how the WITH RECURSIVE command can help here. I tried adding "with recursive", i.e. "with recursive recursive_cluster AS" when defining the CTE, but that just threw another error -

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "with"
  Position: 1230
```

which occurred at the "with recursive" line of code.

Comment: You need to put your query' s updated version with `"with recursive"` and it obviously has a syntax problem. This version without `"with recursive"` is not recursive so it won' t work. To your question "I do not understand how the WITH RECURSIVE command can help here", because how `recursive` queries work in PostgreSQL.